# PHP call function from parent in child best practice

Tags: php

I have a trick question regarding PHP calling a function from parent in child class.
We have 3 scenarios, and I want pros and cons.

```
<?php
class test{
   private $var ;
   public function __construct(){
    $this->var = 'Hello world';
   }

   public function output(){
      echo $var.'<br>';
   }
}
//scenario 1
class test1 extends test{
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
   }
   public function say(){
    parent::output();
   }
}
//scenario 2
class test2 extends test{
   public function __construct(){
    test::__construct();
   }
   public function say(){
    test::output();
   }
}
//scenario 3
class test3 extends test{
    private $handle ;
    public function __construct(){
     $this->handle = new test();
    }
    public function say(){
     $this->handle->output();
    }
}
//finally I can call any 3 cases by one of the below codes
$test1 = new test1();
$test1->say();
//or
$test2 = new test2();
$test2->say();
//or
$test3 = new test3();
$test3->say();
?>
```

Is there a best practice or is there any of the 3 scenarios better than other?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is good practice to use parent.

Answer (score 1):

1) Is correct

2) Is incorrect call the method like a static method.

3) It does not have any sense extend and create in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. All 3 do the same thing whatever if they are incorrect of not making sens. :)

Comment: 3) is called decorator pattern, and actually has good use cases. The only bad thing is that in this example the object to be decorated is instatiated inside the decorator, and not passed into it from outside. So this decorator is unusable for different objects.

Comment: Sven and the class it self is extending. I don't say its incorrect. I say that extend + construct does not have sense

Answer (score 0):

1)
This one is correct, as its calling the parent from its methods.

```
class test1 extends test{
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
   }
   public function say(){
    parent::output();
   }
}
```

2)
The inheritance in here is unnecessary. 
If you choose this implementation, you must change both `output` and construct method to static.

```
//scenario 2
class test2 extends test{
   public function __construct(){
    test::__construct();
   }
   public function say(){
    test::output();
   }
}
```

3)
The inheritance from here is also unnecessary. 
Note here you are using "component over inheritance" pattern which is a good practice as it provides more flexibility, but you must delete the "extends test".

```
//scenario 3
class test3 extends test{
    private $handle ;
    public function __construct(){
     $this->handle = new test();
    }
    public function say(){
     $this->handle->output();
    }
}
```